# How to define a type relative to other type's size?

Tags: c++, types, typedef

Is it possible to define a type in a way that it will always take a half of already defined type size?

```
typedef int16_t myType;
typedef int8_t myTypeHalf;
```

So when I decide to change ***myType*** from ***int16_t*** to ***int32_t***, ***myTypeHalf*** would change automatically to ***int16_t***, so I wouldn't need to worry that I might forget to change ***myTypeHalf***.

```
typedef int32_t myType;
typedef int16_t myTypeHalf;
```

Comment: And what if `myType` is `int8_t`?

Comment: then, `myTypeHalf`, would need to be `int8_t` too, but the question is more about whether it is possible to define such conditions/dependencies. Or is the only way to mention it in the comments and hope that whoever gets to work with the code later follows the comment instructions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a set of template specializations like this:

```
template<size_t Bits> struct SizedInt;
template<> struct SizedInt<8> { using type = std::int8_t; };    
template<> struct SizedInt<16>{ using type = std::int16_t; };
template<> struct SizedInt<32>{ using type = std::int32_t; };
template<> struct SizedInt<64>{ using type = std::int64_t; };

template<size_t Bits>
using SizedInt_t = typename SizedInt<Bits>::type;
```

Then you can define your types like this:

```
using myType = std::int32_t;
using myTypeHalf = SizedInt_t<sizeof(myType) * 4>;
```

Of course, you can use a more complicated mathematical expression to handle special cases (like when `myType` is `std::int8_t`), but I think this gets the idea across.

Comment: This looks a lot more flexible since it uses the size instead of the type.  Now you do not need to worry about unsigned types.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct HalfType
{
    typedef int8_t Type;
};
```

and a bunch of specializations, like:

```
template<>
struct HalfType<int32_t>
{
    typedef int16_t Type;
};

..............
```

The number of possible cases is not that big. You can simply specify them all. Once there is no hallf type for the type passed, the default template will give out `int8_t`. The use should look like

```
HalfType<somePassedType>::Type myVarOfHalfTheSize;
```